# How do I access a VM inside a Linux machine?

Tags: debian, networking, iptables, routing

I have a Debian machine that hosts a virtual machine / Docker container. I would like to access that container from an outside machine, however it's not just a single port that I need access on, since that container hosts a website I need to be able to make requests to different pages, so like "site.com/home" or "site.com/index" and I need to be able to access different ports on the container, so like `192.49.11.1:1234`, where `192.49.11.1` is the container's IP address (that I don't know how it got, exactly).

My network consists of the Debian machine, the external (Windows 10) machine and a router. I'm thinking that if I were to add a record to the router's routing table that tells it to route any requests to `192.49.11.1` to the Debian machine and it would know to route them to the container I would get what I want.

The question is how do I do that AND is this feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since that container hosts a website

The canonical way to do that is to map the ports of the container to ports on the Docker host, using the `-p` option, entries in the Docker Compose YAML file, or whatever you use. If you have multiple ports, map all of them.

> My network consists of the Debian machine, the external (Windows 10) machine and a router.

So you must make the Debian machine part of your network. You didn't tell us **what kind** of VM it is (WSL? Hyper-V?). Google the documentation for whatever kind of VM you are using. (It's pretty difficult with WSL, but there's a work around).

> I'm thinking that if I were to add a record to the router's routing table that tells it to route any requests to 192.49.11.1 to the Debian machine

You don't make requests to the IP of the container (and it likely does not have this address in the first place). You make the requests to the IP of the Debian host, or to the Windows host if you also need port forwarding for WSL on this.